# Check if a substring is repeating in a string

Tags: apex, java

My requirement is to find if a unknown string of 4 chars is repeating of a string of length 16.

So basically, INPUT : "shgtHellorhecHello" Should return true.

Only known thing to us is that the repeating substring if of 4 chars and the full string is if 16 chars.

Please help

Comment: Did you mean we have just the string and size of substring as inputs params and not the actual substring? Also, could you paste what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a Regular Expression:

```
String searchString = 'shgtHellorhecHello';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(.{4}).*\\1');
Boolean repeatFound = p.matcher(searchString).find();
```

This pattern matches "any four characters (`(.{4})`), separated by any number of characters (`.*`), then those same four characters from the first group (`\\1`)".